# reluctance motor sinewave current

Tags: motor, stepper-motor

can i make switched reluctance motor with sinewave input voltage and sinewave current using series LC resonant filter (Inductor L and capacitor C in series resonance (for 50 Hz 0.1H and 100 micro Farad) on the input side of the motor) ?

If i put just like that sinewave voltage, the current will not be sinewave (some kind distorted signal).

Comment: Yes, the current will be distorted. Further, even if the inductor L of your resonant filter will be calculated properly, mind that the rotor winding takes part in the inductance, but also in a variable way, as the reluctance varies while the rotor is turning.

Answer (score 0):

Your question doesn't mention the number of phases of the switched reluctance motor.

In principle it's possible to supply a sine wave to each phase, but they have to lag each other with the same amount, and the sum of the lags should be one period length.

This way you obtained a kind of synchronous motor, but a highly inefficient one. Also the rotational speed should be brought in sync with the frequency supplied before you can connect the power. It simply won't start on its own, unlike most synchronous motors which have a short circuited winding in the rotor making it start as if it were an asynchronous machine.

Why you would want to make it 'resonant' is beyond me, but you can do it.

Even better, if it were a 2 phase motor, you could connect one phase directly to an AC voltage, the other phase through a capacitor, making it possible to drive the whole contraption from one phase voltage. A bit comparable to how a (specially adapted) 3-phase induction machine is fed from a 1 phase voltage.

Comment: Thanks. Standart 3 phase variable reluctance motor.  https://sub.allaboutcircuits.com/images/02437.png

Comment: https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/textbook/alternating-current/chpt-13/reluctance-motor/